# Анонс Winter Bash 2015

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Вот и еще один календарный год подходит к концу, а это может означать лишь одно. Снова наступает время события, которое дарит всем удовольствие – «**Winter Bash**»!

[image]

Начиная с сегодняшнего дня и до конца 3-го января 2016 года вы сможете зарабатывать шляпы за различные достижения на Stack Exchange и хвастаться ими на любом сайте Сети! Так же это означает, что мы должны сказать огромное спасибо удивительному дизайнеру [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), который уже третий год подряд создает прекрасные цифровые шляпы из множества различных концептов.

Шляпы, если вы интересуетесь, означают примерно то же, что и знаки, но **лучше**, потому что вы можете «надеть» их на ваш аватар, который будет отображаться вместе со шляпой на любом сайте Сети. (Еще одно огромное спасибо за любовь к работе [Brian Nickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860000/brian-nickel), благодоря ему шляпы доступны на iOS устройствах в этом году). Условия получения шляп немного отличаются от условий для знаков: для того, чтобы понять, какие шаги необходимо предпринять, чтобы получить головной убор, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [мини-сайт Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). Всего существует 28 шляп, которые вы можете заработать в течении нескольких следующих недель. Хотите узнать сколько секретных шляп мы подготовили для вас в этом году? Все в ваших руках!

После того, как вы заработаете несколько шляп, вы сможете зайти в вашу учётную запись на любом сайте Сети и выбрать шляпу, которую вы хотели бы надеть (или просто насладитесь вашим гардеробом). Для этого просто нажмите на появившуюся зимнюю шапку, украшающую вашу панель знаков.

[image: bobble]

(Нет, вы не можете надеть зимнюю шапку, иначе все ваши знаки замерзнут!)

[image: dialog]

Как только вы определитесь с шапкой, которую хотите надеть, вы сможете изменить её размер или позицию так, чтобы она сосчиталась с вашим аватаром.

[image: controls]

В завершение, нет необходимости беспокоиться об учете шляп самостоятельно. Вы будете получать нотификации о новых шляпах с помощью специального меню Winter Bash.

[image: topbarNotif]

Конечно же, если вы считаете все это глупостью, и не хотите ничего этого видеть – хорошо, мы не будем (очень сильно) осуждать вас. Вы можете отказаться от участия в событии, кликнув на знак снежинки в верхней панели.

[image: topbarSnowflake]

Далее, перейдите по ссылке «я ненавижу шляпы», находящейся в нижнем левом углу всплывающего диалога. На Stack Overflow на английском все будет наоборот: чтобы принять участие в Winter Bash необходимо пройти все эти шаги. Вы можете изменить ваше решение об участии в любое время.

Пожалуйста, учтите, все шляпы растворятся в небытие по прошествию трех недель. Теперь, вперед!

[pdl http://poorlydrawnlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cool-hat.png](http://poorlydrawnlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cool-hat.png)